# Setup proxy server and inject headers (User-Agent)

Tags: windows-7, windows

I'd like to install a proxy server on my machine, but I'd also like to inject some headers with every request made via the proxy.

For example, if I connect to the proxy server on my machine with my phone I want it to automatically set the user agent to one of my choosing. For example FireFox. So any connection made via the proxy will use a FireFox User-Agent.

Do any tools exit for this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems youvwant to modify headers rather then add them. (an important technial dostinction becauseva proxy should add an x-forwarded-for header etc.

Look at Privoxy.